# JPA Entity with inherited key and a one-to-many relation: cannot get a proper foreign key

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I have 3 entities:

1. a Poi entity
2. a PolygonPoi entity that inherits from the Poi entity (also the @Id) via a joined inheritance type.
3. and the Coordinate entity that is connected to the Polygon poi via a many to on relation (1-PolygonPoi N-Coordinates)

My problem is that I can't get proper foreign keys ( I get only only null values) for the Coordinate entity. Coordinate should use the Id of Poi. How do I fix this ??

Here are the three mentioned entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Poi
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    protected String name;
```

---

```
@Entity
public class PolygonPoi extends Poi
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "poi", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    protected List<Coordinate> coordinate = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Coordinate
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne  
    Poi poi;
```

Also It would be nice to get ride of PolygonPoi in the Database entirely, since it does not hold any information beside the relation to the Coordinate.

E:

Here is how my Tables look like:

```
SELECT * FROM POI;
NAME    CREATEDBY  
pp0     1

SELECT * FROM POLYGONPOI;
NAME  
pp0

SELECT * FROM COORDINATE ;
ID      LATITUDE            LONGITUDE           POI_NAME  
1       |30.030000686645508 |50.29999923706055  |null
2       |31.030000686645508 |51.29999923706055  |null
3       |31.030000686645508 |50.29999923706055  |null
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are after with the "Also It would be nice to get ride of PolygonPoi in the Database entirely".  Do you mean you don't want a "PolygonPoi" table? If so, don't use joined inheritance, use single table inheritance.

Comment: I added the Tables that I get on the Database. As you can see POLYGONPOI does not hold any valuable information. If I can not remove POLYGONPOI I rather stay with the useless POLYGONPOI Table than using a single table inheritance.

Comment: I still don't understand.  You have control of the application and what tables it uses.  If there isn't any data, why are you using a POLYGONPOI table?  All data for the PolygonPoi class is in the POI table, so just use single table inheritance.  PolygonPoi can share the POI table with the abstract POI class and other subclasses.

Comment: I am not using a single table inheritance because I have other entities that do have more data and also inherit from Poi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uunless you specify a @JoinColumn annotation and define the foreign key column, JPA will default to using a "poi_NAME" field within the Coordinate table as a foriegn key to Poi.NAME for the Coordinate ->Poi relationship.  This will be set with the name value contained within the referenced poi instance.  If the referenced poi doesn't have a name set - your application is responsible for assigning it as a Poi entity (or subclass) cannot exist without an ID.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific please ? I did add mappedBy on the @OneToMany annotation shouldn’t this handle the mapping of the foreign key ?

Comment: Mappedby tells the PolygonPoi list of coordinates what the relationship in Coordinate is that defines the foreign key.  COORDINATE.POI_NAME  will be null unless you set the Coordinate.poi to a managed Poi entity.  Are you setting both sides of your bidirectional relationship?  When you add a Coordinate to a PolygonPoi, you must also set the Coordinate.poi reference.

Comment: Hmm, no I did not set the Coordinate.poi reference. Shouldn't this be handled by the cascade={CascadeType.ALL} ?? I actually add the PolygonPoi to a User entity and than update it. I want that everything is saved in a chain autocratically when I do this. In the Poi entity I don't have to set the user reference and everything is working fine.

Comment: No.  Mappedby only specifies that your relationship is bidirectional, and that it is controlled by the mapping on the other side.  The other side needs to be set for the foreign key to be updated in the database, but both sides should be maintained by the application to keep the model in synch with the database - JPA does not do relationship maintenance for you.  Just add a helper method to your entity that both adds to the collection and sets the Coordinate.poi reference at the same time.